# Could a damaged sensor cause stripes on the image?

Tags: sensor, repair, equipment-damage

Today I discovered that my camera has started to save pictures like this:
[image: bad stripes]
But, when I use the camera viewfinder, everything looks fine, both via LCD and via the EVF.
I thought it could be the SD card, but it happens also with the internal memory.

What can be, a broken sensor? But, if it is broken sensor, why does the LCD live view work fine?

Between the last "normal" photo and the first "striped" photo the camera did not take any shock, it just sat on a shelf for six months.

Comment: What kind of camera are you using?

Comment: Basically is a Nikon P&S with an EVF and grip to look professional

Comment: If the image looks fine in live view (especially when zoomed all the way in), then it is unlikely the sensor is damaged. This looks like some kind of data corruption, possibly a JPEG that cannot be fully read, but which used pyramid packing or something like that (i.e. the first layer or two of image detail can be read, but the rest is unreadable.) I'm stretching a bit...I've never seen this particular kind of "corruption" before...but I can't imagine the sensor is bad if Live View works.

Comment: If you have another SD card, try on that one. It looks like file corruption to me too, so one way to find out is to swap cards. Could still be a hardware fault in the camera, but swapping cards will at least eliminate that as a source (or prove it).

Comment: I tried with no SD card at all (the camera has a small internal memory for demo, like for 6 pictures), and I still get the problem

Comment: It could be a damaged sensor, as the live view is significantly down sampled; however, I doubt it. It is far more likely to be an issue with how the JPEG is being written. If your camera has an option to write a RAW image (unlikely in a P&S), try that. Also look for firmware updates and or any option to reset to factory defaults. It is possible that the camera's software has been corrupted and updating/resetting it may help.

If none of that helps, I suspect that something other than the sensor has been damaged, likely something in the image / file save process.

Comment: No firmware updates, and resetting did not help. What's weird is that if I record a 640x480 movie, I get no stripes at all; if I take a 640x480 shot, I get lots of stripes

Comment: I thought it might be a speed of read issue (live view can scan more slowly so it could be missed, but shutter rate should then impact it as faster shutters have to scan quicker).  Since shutter speed was reported as not altering it, it likely is not the issue.

Comment: Just curious, can we get a follow-up?  What did you do with the camera and how did you resolve it?

Comment: The problem wasn't solved. I am planning to use the camera as a security camera via rca plug, since the live view works without any issue. Or I will open it just for fun...

Comment: I took it apart and put back with care, now the live view also contains the stripes, and are much more intense. I'm an engineer, I'm used to take apart stuff, I never saw something this easy to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given all the information you've provided in your follow-up comments, I think we can rule out a damaged SD card, and conclude that something in the camera itself is malfunctioning.

While it may not be the actual sensor that's damaged (it may actually be the CPU or internal memory), nonetheless the camera needs to go in for repair or replacement.

Take it to a service centre.  If under warranty, they may replace it.  Otherwise, if you take it to an authorised repair centre, they may be able to swap the logic board out.

Though in this case it may not be worth it.  Your camera is essentially a point&shoot camera that approximates an SLR in size and weight only.  You could upgrade to an actual SLR for a surprising low amount these days, for example a Nikon D3100, and get 4 times the image quality immediately, along with faster focusing and less shutter delay.